# Unassigned variables have random values

Tags: c, struct

```
#define MAX_ENTRY 100     

//define struct
typedef struct StudentRecords
{
int StudentID; 
     char *Firstname; 
     char *Lastname; 
     char *Department; 
     float GPA; 
} STUDENTRECORDS; 

//initialize
STUDENTRECORDS StudentRecords[MAX_ENTRY];
```

skip to this inside main...

```
//allocate memory for the strings as required by the assignment
for(i=0;i<MAX_ENTRY;i++)
     {
        StudentRecords[i].Firstname = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
        StudentRecords[i].Lastname = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
        StudentRecords[i].Department = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);        
    }

while(EOF!=fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %s %f\n", &StudentRecords[i].StudentID, StudentRecords[i].Firstname, StudentRecords[i].Lastname, StudentRecords[i].Department, &StudentRecords[i].GPA))
    {
        printf("%d %s %s %s %f\n", StudentRecords[i].StudentID, StudentRecords[i].Firstname, StudentRecords[i].Lastname, StudentRecords[i].Department, StudentRecords[i].GPA);
        i++;
    }

}
```

The input file looks like this:

```
2040003 AAAA BBBBBBBBB ComputerScience 3.45

2040002 AAA CCC ElectricalEngineering 3.01

2040005 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBB ComputerScience 3.60
```

How is it I'm getting StudentRecords[i].StudentID's ranging from large negative numbers, to 0, to large positive numbers?

The lines in the input file DO make it into the struct, but also all these random entries. I figured if I didn't assign anything to unused spots in the struct (it's currently length 100), they would just stay blank.

If I change the size of the struct (honestly I don't know how to make it dynamic, maybe that would help) to something smaller than 100, I get LESS random entries, but they still exist.

Comment: Try changing `EOF!=fscanf(...` to `5==fscanf(...`

Comment: And change `char *Firstname;` to `char Firstname[100];`, etc

Comment: I cant change fscanf to a constant because the number of lines in the file could change.

Comment: I've also updated my question to that it shows i've allocated memory.

Comment: `"I cant change fscanf to a constant because the number of lines in the file could change`" `scanf` (and friends) return **the number of matches assigned to arguments** (not lines).  Always check that `scanf` returns the number of expected matches (not just EOF).

Comment: If your StudentID has more than 10 digits, you are at risk of overflowing an integer type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem it sounds like your having issues with printing out the structs with the empty ones giving you random stuff. This is because your StudentRecords array isn't statically declared so the members are not zeroed upon initialization. As a result the contents of each struct will be random/garbage until you assign something. If you want to initialize the contents of your structs to say NULL/zeros try this:

```
memset( &StudentRecords, 0, sizeof(StudentRecords));
```

This however will not fix your problem of having empty/unused structs in your array. For that you could simply add logic to skip the empty ones when you're printing them out. There are many options for determining that, one simple one is to add a flag to your struct:

```
int isUsed;
```

It will be initialize to zero with the memset. When you load the file, simply set the value to `1`. Or you can use other combinations of sentient values/logic.

Comment: Thanks, I already had logic checking StudentID for a length 7 which ruled out most of the random assignments. But, there was a few that were 7 digits that were passing through. memset worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that no space is allocated to store the strings. One way of doing this is to change your structure to:

```
typedef struct StudentRecords {
    int StudentID; 
    char Firstname[100]; 
    char Lastname[100]; 
    char Department[100]; 
    float GPA; 
} STUDENTRECORDS;
```

Then you should also change your `scanf` to:

```
while(5 == fscanf(fp, "%d %99s %99s %99s %f\n", 
    &StudentRecords[i].StudentID, 
    StudentRecords[i].Firstname, 
    StudentRecords[i].Lastname, 
    StudentRecords[i].Department, 
    &StudentRecords[i].GPA))
    // ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely forgot to add those lines to the question. I've edited my question to contain allocating space for the strings.